# Toggle google maps markers based on id

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, laravel, google-maps-api-3

I have a map that displays markers through a `for loop`.

```
function map_view_initialize() {
        var properties = <?php echo is_array($properties) ? json_encode($properties) : $properties; ?>;
        var index;
        var mapOptions = {
            center: {lat: 32.752601, lng: 9.801254},
            zoom: 12,
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_view_canvas'),
                mapOptions);
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        for (var index = 0; index < properties.length; index++) {

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(properties[index].property_latitude, properties[index].property_longitude);
            var agent = properties[index].agent_firstname + ' ' + properties[index].agent_lastname;
            var propertyName = properties[index].property_name;
            var agentId = properties[index].agent_id;
            var propertyLocation = properties[index].location_name;
            var owner = properties[index].owner_firstname + ' ' + properties[index].owner_lastname;
            var ownerTel = properties[index].owner_telephone_number;
            var markerContent = "<div><h4>" + propertyName + "</h4>\n\
            <h5>Location: " + propertyLocation + "</h5>\n\
            <p>" + owner + " " + ownerTel + "</p>\n\
            </div>";

            var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                agent:agentId,
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                labelContent: agent,
                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
                labelClass: "labels",
                labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
            });

            marker.content = markerContent;

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infoWindow.setContent(this.content);
                infoWindow.open(this.getMap(), this);
            });
        }
 }
```

I also have a group of buttons which are related with the `agentId` property of each marker.

```
@foreach($agents as $agent)
   <button id="{{$agent->person_id}}" onclick="filterMarkers(this.id);" type='button' class='btn btn-success btnMargin btn-xs'>{{$agent->agent_lastname}} {{$agent->agent_firstname}}</button>          
@endforeach
```

When i press one of these buttons then this function runs

```
function filterMarkers(agentId){
                var element = document.getElementById(agentId);
                var cls = hasClass(element,'notActive');

                if(!cls){
                    element.classList.add("notActive");
                    element.style.opacity = 0.5;
                }
                else if(cls){
                    element.classList.remove("notActive");
                    element.style.opacity = 1;  
                }
}
```

I want to toggle the visibility of each marker by using my buttons (see the second block of code). For example when i press the button with the `id=1` i need to hide/show the markers that the `agentId` property equals to 1.

Comment: can you putt that on-line? fiddle, codepen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an index of the marker associated to the agentId eg (defined in global area):

```
 var markerIndex=[];
```

In the loop you must set for every agentId the associated marker

```
markerInded[agentId]=marker
```

and for toggle the marker you need  functions for hide and show the marker   eg

```
toggleMarkerOff(agentId){
  markerIndex[agentId].setMap(null); 
}
toggleMarkerOff(agentId){
  markerIndex[agentId].setMap(map); 
}
```

then you can call the prpoer function in the related element event